# opening jquery mobile popup on ajaxStart()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

I want to show a revolving loader on `ajaxStart`. I've used a popup for this so that the background fades out and becomes inactive. That said, if there are other ways to achieve this (instead of using a popup), id be willing to try them out too.

The problem is, while the same function containing the AJAX call is executed on both page-load and a button click, the loader only shows up the first time - on page load. I put some console logs and verified that the `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` do get triggered, but the pop-up fails to open when the AJAX call is made following the button click.

**JavaScript :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
        $("#loader").html("<img src='../images/ajax-loader.gif'/>").popup("open");
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $("#loader").popup("close");
    });
    // do other stuff

    loadData();

    $("#button").click(function(){
        loadData(); 
    });
});

function loadData(){
     //make an ajax call to fetch data
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="popup" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" class="loader1" 
  id="loader" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="none" data-dismissible="false" >
</div>
```

What could be the issue, or are there other solutions altogether to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Not sure if it is your problem, but jQuery Mobile can only show one popup at a time (for now). If a popup is already open, trying to open a second one will silently fail.

Comment: yes, the button click is indeed in another pop-up! is there a work around?

Comment: I'm afraid that the problem is caused by using `.ready()` as the popup doesn't respond the second time. `.ready()` trigger once only and it's equivalent to `pageinit` in jQM. Use jQM events instead ie.e `pageshow`, `pagebeforeshow`..etc... What version are you using? Also, use `$('selector').on('click', function () { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

First, the short answer:  jQuery Mobile only supports one active popup at a time (for now). The [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/) says:

> **Note: Chaining of popups not allowed**
>   The framework does not currently
>   support chaining of popups so it's not possible to embed a link from
>   one popup to another popup. All links with a `data-rel="popup"` inside a
>   popup will not do anything at all.

I bumped against this issue a few times in the past and had to hack my way around it. The following code is the solution I'm currently using and works quite well so far (with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2):

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    $.widget("mobile.popup", $.mobile.popup, {
        _trigger: function(type, event, data) {
            return this._suspended ? undefined : this._super(type, event, data);
        },
        _openPrereqsComplete: function() {
            this._super();
            delete this._suspended;
        },
        open: function(options) {
            var activePopup = $.mobile.popup.active;
            if (activePopup) {
                activePopup._suspended = true;
                activePopup._close(true);
                this.element.one("popupafterclose", function() {
                    activePopup.open();
                });
            }
            this._super(options);
        }
    });
});
```

In a nutshell, that code extends the popup widget in-place to introduce a "suspended" state. All events are muted if a popup widget is in that state.

Then, the `open()` method is overloaded to detect if another popup is already active. If that's the case, it suspends and closes that popup (without performing any animation, so it is closed right away), then opens the new one and schedules the un-suspending and re-opening of the previous popup when the new one is closed.

Note that code binds to the `mobileinit` event, so it has to run *after* jQuery is included but *before* jQuery Mobile is included. Otherwise, it will be too late to extend the popup widgets that were instantiated during page initialization.

Comment: I want to know to make nutshells, working with them seems to be fun :)

Comment: I am actually closing the current pop-up before opening the next one i.e., before calling loadData(). But it still doesnt work. I played around a little bit and saw that if i introduce a delay in execution, the loader popup opens up fine. But is there a prettier way to do this, i dont want to write setTimeouts everywhere that i make an ajax call

Comment: @deepa.g, is your popup configured to perform a closing animation? If that's the case, it won't close right away, unless you pass `true` to its internal `_close()` method. Something like `$("#yourElement").closest(".ui-popup").data("mobilePopup")._close(true);` can solve your problem (it did for me).